# Curve Fitting through Bayesian Posterior Optimization

Tags: python, distribution, curve-fitting, bayesian

I am attempting to use Python PYMC3 package to create a posterior predictive distribution on my data, get cumulative and conditional probability as the final result.

I am studying 3 types of life expectancy: 12 months, 24 months and 36 months. Individual life expectancy groups have a different historical shape of when the death occurred within their life.

For example, here is the 24 month life expectancy patter based on historical information:

[image]
So I am exploring Bayesian methods for curve fitting and have been experimenting with Negative Binomial distribution to create a curve that fits this data. (I am thinking that lognormal would be a more appropriate fit, but I did not have a chance to adjust my code.

Below is the code/logic I used to fit the curve:

```
# life_expectancy = 12, 24, 36
# dead = 1, 0

indiv_traces = {}

# Convert categorical variables to integer
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

participants_idx = le.fit_transform(df_comb_clean[(df_comb_clean['dead']==1)]['life_expectancy'])
participants = le.classes_
n_participants = len(participants)

for p in participants:
    with pm.Model() as model:
        alpha = pm.Uniform('alpha', lower=0, upper=100)
        mu = pm.Uniform('mu', lower=0, upper=100)

        data = df_comb_clean[(df_comb_clean['dead']==1) & (df_comb_clean['life_expectancy']==p)]['month'].values
        y_est = pm.NegativeBinomial('y_est', mu=mu, alpha=alpha, observed=data)

        y_pred = pm.NegativeBinomial('y_pred', mu=mu, alpha=alpha)

        start = pm.find_MAP()
        step = pm.Metropolis()
        trace = pm.sample(20000, step, start=start, progressbar=True)


        indiv_traces[p] = trace
```

Results:

```
# Optimization life_expectancyinated successfully.
#          Current function value: 133.738083
#          Iterations: 11
#          Function evaluations: 19
#          Gradient evaluations: 19
# 100%|██████████| 20000/20000 [00:12<00:00, 1659.15it/s]
# Optimization life_expectancyinated successfully.
#          Current function value: 679.448463
#          Iterations: 17
#          Function evaluations: 25
#          Gradient evaluations: 25
# 100%|██████████| 20000/20000 [00:12<00:00, 1614.50it/s]
# Optimization life_expectancyinated successfully.
#          Current function value: 812.109878
#          Iterations: 18
#          Function evaluations: 201
#          Gradient evaluations: 198
# 100%|██████████| 20000/20000 [00:12<00:00, 1570.42it/s]
```

Now I am graphing my posterior predictive distribution:

```
combined_y_pred = np.concatenate([v.get_values('y_pred') for k, v in indiv_traces.items()])

x_lim = 24
y_pred = trace.get_values('y_pred')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
fig.add_subplot(211)

fig.add_subplot(211)

_ = plt.hist(combined_y_pred, range=[5, x_lim], bins=x_lim, histtype='stepfilled', color=colors[1])
_ = plt.xlim(4, x_lim)
_ = plt.ylim(0, 5000)
_ = plt.ylabel('Frequency')
_ = plt.title('Posterior predictive distribution')

fig.add_subplot(212)
# ter

#     df_comb_co['month'].values, 
_ = plt.hist(df_comb_clean[df_comb_clean['dead']==1]['month'].values,range=[5, x_lim], bins=x_lim, histtype='stepfilled')    
_ = plt.xlim(4, x_lim)
_ = plt.xlabel('Month')
_ = plt.ylim(0, 50)
_ = plt.ylabel('Frequency')
_ = plt.title('Distribution of observed data')

plt.tight_layout()
```

Then get the following output:
[image]

So now, I want to extract my results and transform them into conditional (based on month) curve that would fit my initial data. I did a basic attempt via the following code for life expectancy of 24 months:

```
def life_expectancy_y_pred(life_expectancy):
    """Return posterior predictive for person"""
    ix = np.where(participants == life_expectancy)[0][0]
    return trace['y_pred']

life_expectancy = 24
x = np.linspace(4, life_expectancy, num=life_expectancy)
num_samples = float(len(life_expectancy_y_pred(life_expectancy)))
prob_lt_cum_x = [sum(life_expectancy_y_pred(life_expectancy) < i)/num_samples for i in x]
```

Below are my results where blue is actual, orange is negative binomial fit I did manually in python and the yellow is what I got from bayesian optimization process.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong as my fit through bayesian is pretty bad. I want the right tail to be relatively where it is but the cusp similar to orange line.[image]

I don't want to drop the process as of yet.

Comment: Did you find the answer?